# Fractran program size

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

On the subject of lower and upper bounds of John H. Conway's Fractran program size, if you tried to evaluate these using the pumping lemma, couldn't you create an infinity of fractions evaluating the same program with very large gaps in the index N?